# Forcing command to run on logout

Tags: ubuntu, login, startup, pam

I want to run a command, say touch ~/test.txt every time I'm logging out from my computer. Is that possible, and if so how should I go about doing this? I've looked at other responses but they were a bit too obscure. Specifically one mentioned that I should be finding some sort of 'common' file if I want this command to run for all user logout events. Any help is welcome, thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? If it has systemd, then there should be a `Before` target (haven't checked). If it is, you'll want to write a systemd unit which executes your command .

Comment: My version is 16.04.3. I can't find this before target, should that be a file in pam.d?

Comment: Logout target doesn't look that straightforward. You can run `systemctl list-unit-files -t target` to get a list of all targets but without knowing off the top of the head, one would need to lookup likely candidates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "logging out" as closing GUI session..

Depends what GUI you use:

Gnome: The script `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` is run by root whenever someone quits his X session.

Source: [How can I make a script run automatically after gdm login and logout? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85985/how-can-i-make-a-script-run-automatically-after-gdm-login-and-logout)

Unity (Ubuntu default): in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. 
below a chapter of `[SeatDefaults]`
a command `session-cleanup-script=/path/to/your-script.sh` will do the trick.

Source: [How to run a script at logout | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624374/how-to-run-a-script-at-logout)

KDE will run `/usr/shutdown` script.

Source: [How to run a logoff script | KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=24484)

Comment: Do you know any general solution with systemd?

Comment: Will this run with SUDO permissions?

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't talking about the GUI, it depends on your shell:

bash has a ~/.bash_logout file that gets executed when a login shell closes.

zsh has a .zlogout (in your home or in the $ZDOTDIR directory).

You can put pretty much anything in either and have it run when you log out.

Comment: So I tried running a random touch logout command, didnt work. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have a .zlogin file that just runs "fortune" and a .zlogout with: "touch ~/logout_time" -- not sure about the bash version, but make sure you are running a login shell (see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell). GL!