# What is chsh command use for?

Tags: linux, shell

I know that chsh is use to change the login shell with the shell listed in this file. Okay,

But what is actually Login shell is? Can anyone tell me this as simple as you can? ;)

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) is pretty good 'one-stop shop' summary from @Gilles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the shell you are running when you login.
E.g. when I `ssh` into my remote servers, I like to have `bash`:

```
chsh       [ENTER]
/bin/bash  [ENTER]
```

You might want to [read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) [more](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch03_04.htm) [on](http://howtolamp.com/articles/difference-between-login-and-non-login-shell/) [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155865/what-are-login-and-non-login-shells) topic:

> A login shell is the first process that executes under your user ID when you log in for an interactive session.

Answer (score 2):

The login shell, as the name says, is the shell (`bash`, `zsh`, etc) that is given to an user when they log in and where they type commands.

It's stored as the last field in `/etc/passwd`:

```
jdoe:x:1031:1031:John Doe:/home/jdoe:/bin/bash
```

Comment: “It's stored as the last field in `/etc/passwd`” ... on systems which use `/etc/passwd` to define their users.