# How to make mkinitcpio busybox ash to source /etc/profile?

Tags: arch-linux, busybox, ash

Arch Linux `/usr/lib/initcpio/busybox` is owned by package mkinitcpio-busybox 1.27.2-1 and is [configured low on features](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/config?h=packages/mkinitcpio-busybox), for example CONFIG_FEATURE_USE_INITTAB is not set.

In a custom initramfs, containing that busybox, I managed to get ssh network logins that do source `/etc/profile` working. Also there is an **ash** shell prompt visible on the VGA monitor.

However that "vga" shell doesn't source `/etc/profile`.
Q:[Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell) makes me think that this shell is not a login shell.
That shell is started by `/init`:

```
exec setsid sh -c 'exec sh </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1'
```

Regression:

- `exec setsid sh -c 'exec sh -i </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1'`
- `exec setsid sh -c 'exec sh - </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1'`
- `exec setsid sh -c 'exec -sh </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1'`

How to make this `busybox` `ash` shell to source `/etc/profile` and/or make it an (auto) login shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conventionally, a shell acts as a login shell if it is invoked with a command name beginning with `-`. `exec -sh` would work is you had an executable called `-sh` in the path. BusyBox ash also supports the `-l` option, so you can run `sh -l`.

When you log in, the `login` program (or `sshd`, or whatever is handling the login) takes care of running the user's shell with a leading `-` in the command name (the command name doesn't have to be the same as the name of the executable, it's just a very common convention which `login` violates on purpose). Here, “whatever is handling the login” is your mini-script, so you have to take care of it.