# The Shell initially Invoked After I Power On My Computer is Login or Non-login Shell?

Tags: bash

I read multiple articles refering the login shell and non-login shell,
still, I am very confused.
[Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell)
[The UNIX School: Login shell or a non-login shell?](http://www.theunixschool.com/2010/05/login-shell-or-non-login-shell.html)

Put it simple,
the shell I start from my own computer after I power on it,
Isn't it a login shell or non-login shell?

```
    $ echo $SHELL
    /bin/bash
    $ echo $0
    -bash
```

Additionally, Could you please help to determine taht the shell called from a program is login shell or not?

```
    import subprocess
    subprocess.run('ls -l', shell=True)
```

Comment: From one of the answers to the above: "# "-" is the first character. Therefore, this is a login shell.", and as for the program, that depends on on the program, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237672/70524):

> ```
> prompt> echo $0
> -bash # "-" is the first character. Therefore, this is a login shell.
> ```

So your first example shows a login shell.

As also noted in the same answer,

> Information can be found in `man bash` (search for Invocation). Here
>   is an excerpt:
>
> > A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a `-`, or
> >     one started with the `--login` option.

And from [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

> ... Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> ```
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
> ```

Since the only option given is `-c`, it's not a login shell.