# SSH script does not have access to full path variable

Tags: linux, ssh

When I `ssh` into host and `echo $PATH`:

```
$ ssh my@host
$ echo $PATH
```

I get a different value for `$PATH` than when I run a script locally:

```
ssh my@host '\
    echo $PATH;'
```

Any idea why?

**NOTE:** It seems I don't get the full path variable when `ssh`ing from a script versus [other] CLI.

Comment: ssh opens login shell and what happens depends on the shell you use and
your setup.  For example if you use `bash` only `/etc/profile` is
processed.

Comment: show us, don't make us guess. What was the output?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to bash script worked

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that when you run a command through ssh (`ssh user@host 'command'`) it opens a non-login shell. An excellent breakdown of the differences between a login shell and a non-login shell can be found [at this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell). Essentially, what is causing you issue is that when you run the command through ssh your `~/.bash_profile` is not sourced, meaning any modifications to the path it makes will not be available.

The solution is to either move these into your `~/.bashrc`, which is sourced on opening a non-login shell, or as you found out, sourcing your `.bash_profile` directly in the script.