# Is there an invoked file for dash and sh as non login shells in /etc directory?

Tags: shell, dash

`/etc/profile` can be invoked by `sh` and `dash` inside an interactive login mode. Is there any file in `/etc` directory to be invoked when they are in an interactive non-login mode?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "can be invoked by `/etc/profile`"? It's usually the shell that invokes that file, not the other way around.  Your shell's manual should tell you exactly what files are sourced by the shell in interactive and non-interactive modes. Note that `sh` may be implemented by any number of shells, so the manual to check is the manual for the shell that implements `sh`.

Comment: I edited my question according to your comment. The problem I have with is the default `sh` which invoked by just typing `sh`, same for `dash`. I suppose they have files indicated by `ENV` variable (check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I dont know how to find it.

Comment: Simply `echo "$ENV"` in the shell would tell you that. Please notice that per the standard, `ENV` can also contain variables that are expanded by the shell -- eg. `ENV='/etc/shrc-$machine'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dash` shell (and `sh` if implemented by `dash`) reads `/etc/profile` when started as a login shell. Then it reads `~/.profile`.  The `~/.profile` file may set and export the `ENV` environment variable.  This variable should hold the path to a file that is sourced by non-login shells.  This is usually done on a user-by-user basis, and not in any file in `/etc`.

From the `dash` manual (my emphasis):

> If the environment variable `ENV` is set on entry to an
>        interactive shell, or is set in the `.profile` of a login shell, the shell
>        next reads commands from the file named in `ENV`.  **Therefore, a user should
>        place commands that are to be executed only at login time in the `.profile`
>        file, and commands that are executed for every interactive shell inside
>        the `ENV` file.**  To set the `ENV` variable to some file, place the following
>        line in your `.profile` of your home directory
>
> ```
> ENV=$HOME/.shinit; export ENV
> ```
>
> substituting for `.shinit` any filename you wish.

When calling `sh` or `dash` to create an interactive non-login shell session from some other shell or process, just make sure that `ENV` is set to the appropriate shell initialization file.  This can be done from any Bourne-type shell using

```
ENV="$HOME/.shinit" sh
```

or

```
ENV="$HOME/.shinit" dash
```

Answer (score 0):

One more thing about these commands: they all invoke, /bin/sh (often the dash shell on unix-like systems) but they invoke it as a login shell, not an interactive shell.  So the file pointed to by ENV will not get executed, only the hardwired /etc/profile and ~/.profile.

In order to get ENV read, it seems you must put "sh -i -c " in front of your shell commands and quote the command that follows the -c.

```
sh_command = 'sh -i -c "' + command + ' ' + args.join(' ') + '"'
env = { 'ENV' => Your.shellrc_file }
std_out, std_err, status = Open3.capture3(env, sh_command)
```

Then you suffer the very slight inefficiency of having the login shell invoke the interactive shell, but ENV will no longer be ignored.  If you prefer bash, this also allows you to change sh->bash or ksh or zsh or fish, etc.