# 'getenforce' command works locally but not through ssh

Tags: bash, centos, ssh, command-not-found

I am trying to determine whether or not a number of CentOS servers have SELinux enabled.

To do this, I am using the `getenforce` command.

When I run the command locally on a single server, it either returns `Enforcing` or `Disabled`.

When I try and run the command in the format `ssh sysadmin@server.org "getenforce"` it returns `bash: getenforce: command not found`

Is there a reason the command will work when logged on locally to the server but be unable to be found when using SSH?

Note: this only happens on servers where the command would return `Enforcing`. If a server has SELinux disabled it will return `Disabled` when running the command via SSH.

Comment: Call the command with its full path when using it though SSH?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior if you log in `ssh sysadmin@server` and then execute `getenforce` in your login shell?

Comment: No, the command returns as expected @user4556274

Comment: possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856

Answer (score 1):

Following advice from @Kusalananda♦, I referenced the absolute path when using the command like this:

`ssh sysadmin@server.org "/usr/sbin/getenforce"`