# What is the startup script on Alpine Linux when you login. (I want my aliasses when I log in)

Tags: bash, docker, startup, alpine-linux

For Docker Containers we use Alpine Linux, like Node:Alpine, to make our images as small as possible.
But somethimes you want to login on that Container.
It would be convenient to have your aliases in that Container.

When we use standard Linux, we map a .bashrc to /root/.bashrc and have all our aliasses available.

But I cannot find the .bashrc equivalent for Alpine Linix.

I've tried:

- .bashrc
- .bash_profile
- .profile
- .ash_profile
- .ashrc

All not working.

### Additional information

Alpine Linux is started in a Docker Container.

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build .
```

#### Login to the container

I use the following command from the Host (my OSX macbook)

```bsh
docker exec -it <containerName> /bin/sh
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
  jobrunner:
    build:
      context: ./build
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: jobrunner:1.0
    volumes:
      - ./deployment/jobs/root/.bashrc:/root/.bashrc
      - ./deployment/jobs/root/.bashrc:/root/.profile
      - ./logs:/usr/src/app/logs
      - ./data:/usr/src/app/data
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: JobHelloWorld
    command: ["node", "./src/job_starter.js"]
```

Starting the container with:

```bsh
docker-compose up -d
```

#### In the Container

When I enter the container with

```bsh
docker exec -it <containername> /bin/sh
```

and then the output of the commands requested in the comments:

```bsh
/usr/src/app # echo $SHELL

/usr/src/app # ps -p $$
ps: unrecognized option: p
BusyBox v1.32.1 () multi-call binary.

Usage: ps [-o COL1,COL2=HEADER] [-T]

Show list of processes

    -o COL1,COL2=HEADER Select columns for display
    -T          Show threads
/usr/src/app #
```

#### ps -ef

I guess the output of 'ps -ef' is also intersting:

```bsh
/usr/src/app # ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 sleep 360d
    8 root      0:00 sh
   16 root      0:00 ps -ef
```

it shows the sh shell (correct?). But the startup of /bin/sh does not work.

#### ps aux | grep $$

```bsh
/usr/src/app # ps aux | grep $$
   19 root      0:00 /bin/sh
   26 root      0:00 grep 19
```

#### /bin/sh is a link

```bsh
/usr/src/app # ls -la /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Apr 14 10:25 /bin/sh -> /bin/busybox
```

#### Small test changing .profile

```bsh
/usr/src/app # cat ~/.profile
alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -la'

export foo="bar"

/usr/src/app #
/usr/src/app # echo $foo

/usr/src/app #
/usr/src/app # . ~/.profile
Job-/usr/src/app# echo $foo
bar
Job-/usr/src/app#
```

As you see, the .profile does work, it just is not executed upon log in onto Alpine Linux in a Docker environment, or Alpine does not execute .profile upon login.

#### Does anybody know what the startup script is for an interactive session on Alpine Linux?

#### Or: Does anybody know why Docker does not execute .profile upon login from 'docker exec'.

Comment: What shell do you run on alpine? You can see your default login shell with `echo $SHELL` and you can see what you're currently running with `ps -p $$`. Please [edit] your question and add the output of both commands.

Comment: Question updated with output of the commands you mentioned.

Comment: `/bin/sh` should be a symlink most likely. Where does it point to?

Comment: /bin/sh points to /bin/busybox  Which is correct since busybox is the default shell for Alpine. (Why it does not present itself under the $SHELL env var I don't know). Default startup script for busybox is .profile, but that did not work.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about the `ps -p`, it looks like you are using busybox `ps` but yes, it does indeed look like you are using a simple `sh`. Most likely busybox `sh` as well. Just to be sure, you can check with `ps aux | grep $$`.  You say that `~/.profile` didn't work? That suggests you aren't running a login shell. Which is odd. When/how do you log into the container? If you add `export foo="bar"` to `/etc/profile`, then log into the container and run `echo $foo`, do you get `bar`?

Comment: Hang on. do you issue the `docker exec -it <containername> /bin/sh` manually? Can you change that to `docker exec -it <containername> /bin/sh -l`? That will launch a login shell which should let you use `~/.profile`.

Comment: Yes!! That was it. You need to use "-l" in the docker exec command. Never saw that before and I don't need that when log in on Ubuntuy containers (then the .bashrc gets executed). 
Thanks @terdon for your help

Answer (score 5):

Big thanks for @terdon for his time and help.

When log in on Alpine Linux in a Docker Container, you need to use the following command to get the .profile executed:

```bsh
docker exec -it <containerName> /bin/sh -l
```

Notice the -l ('l' for Login? :-) ) at the end. That makes the Alpine shell start [a login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/22222) which means that it reads `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, so I can use those files to define my aliases.

You don't need it for Ubuntu Containers though.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the environment variable `$ENV` to the path of a script you want to run on login. This avoids the need to pass `-l` as an argument to `/bin/sh`.

Example:

```
ENV ENV=/root/.ashrc
```

This sources `/root/.ashrc` on startup.

Comment: The first `ENV` needs to be either lowercase (the env(1) utility), in which case it lacks the command following the assignment of the environment, or changed into `export`.

Comment: @Vilinkameni This is not a shell command. This is a Dockerfile instruction. See [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env).

Answer (score 1):

To log in a user in the Alpine Linux Docker container, *using their configured login shell*, use `login -f username`.

For example,

```bash
docker exec -it mycontainer login -f root
```

If the user has a password set, and you want to use it, remove `-f` from the command.

This will cause the user's configured login shell to be used as the login shell, running *as* a login shell, which means it will read whatever shell initialisation files the shell would ordinarily read when running as a login shell (`/etc/zsh/zprofile` and `~/.zprofile` in the case of `zsh`, for example).