Why isn't bash reading my `~/.profile`?
It has been eons since I had to set up a dev environment and I do need to run some python (CSVkit, specifically).
The default .profile definitely adds my private bin to my path:
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

But when I do printenv PATH it is not there. If I run source ~/.profile it does get added to my PATH.
I definitely don't have a ~/.bash_login or ~/.bash_profile -- so why would bash not read my local .profile?
adding in answer to questions:

I'm definitely running bash.
I haven't edited ~/.profile ever -- it's been there, hanging out, since I set the machine up last year. So this isn't a question of edits not loading.


Are you starting a login shell or a non-login shell?

Are you sure your login shell isn't, for example, zsh (the default shell on MacOS)? Did you log out and log back in after adding that code to your .profile? If you add declare -p PATH to your .profile immediately after the fi line in your question, do you see the contents of PATH output when you log in and, if so, does it start with the directory you're adding (maybe your code adds it but some later code sets PATH to an explicit value)?

@EdMorton Definithely bash.

@steeldriver I am just launching terminal in gnome. So non-login.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/

@Amanda - you just answered your own question then ... add the PATH statement to /etc/profile (so it should be in the env for everything under your gnome desktop) or in your ~/.bashrc ... or, another alternative, edit the gnome-terminal to include a -l for the shell it invokes, forcing it to be a login-shell.

... iirc gnome-terminal has a check box to run a login shell - see for example Terminal preferences › Profile Preferences » Login shells

@tink Is there a reason not to add that as an answer?

@Amanda - it's all already there, both in Marcus' question and in comments here. Just not spelt out explicitly. I didn't see any added value by mentioning a few options that one could find in the man-pages trivially (or by looking at doco for Gnome terminal [I don't use Gnome so don't know anything about its doco]).

~/.profile is simply not one of the files that bash reads *in every case. It first executes /etc/profile. And then it looks for ~/.bash_profile, if it finds that, executes it, and only if it doesn't, looks for ~/.bash_login; if that exists, executes it, and only if doesn't, tries ~/.profile.
So, it would seem you have a ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login, or this isn't actually executed as login shell!
Source: man bash, "INVOCATION".

Yes, indeed, conventions have changed in the last 30+ years. :)

As I said, though: I confirmed that  neither ~/.bash_profile nor ~/.bash_login exist.

But did you confirm that you started a login shell?

@chepner Nothing in this answer discusses the login vs non-login question.

@Amanda actually, my answer does ask specifically whether "this isn't actually executed as login shell".
