# How do I tell whether I'm in a non-login shell or a login shell?

Tags: shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a shell is login/interactive/batch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch)

And what's the benefits of non-login shell over login shell?

Comment: See also [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell/46856#46856)

Answer (score 4):

You can tell whether you're in a login shell using `shopt`:

```
dennis@lightning:~$ shopt login_shell
login_shell     off
```

As for the benefits: login shells generally do a bit more initialization (such as setting environment variables and cd'ing into $HOME) which aren't necessary for other shells. On the other hand, by default any shell launched from the gui is *not* a login shell, so most people configure their shell initscripts (`~/.bashrc` etc) to do all initialization for both login and non-login shells.

Comment: Yes for `bash` the configuration is often done in `~/.bashrc` which is sourced in `~/.bash_profile` to make life easier.