# History expansion in scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-history, history-expansion

I have the following Bash script

```
case $- in (*H*) echo enabled ;; (*) echo disabled ;; esac
set -H
case $- in (*H*) echo enabled ;; (*) echo disabled ;; esac
pwd
last_command="!!"
echo $last_command
```

which prints

```
disabled
enabled
/home/user
!!
```

The first line of code checks to see if history expansion is enabled. The second enables history expansion. The third is the same as the first. Then its runs `pwd` and finally assigns what should be last command to `last_command` and prints this variable.

The history is not expanding. What is going on?

Comment: Closely related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384861/117549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a non-interactive shell, you must specifically *also* enable command history:

```
set -o history
set -o histexpand
```

Then your example will work:

```
disabled
enabled
/home/schaller/tmp/502442
last_command="pwd"
pwd
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I make is so that I can access the history from the shell that is running the script and use history expansion is a similar fashion?

Comment: @History_expansion According to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384867/85039) history expansion is disabled for scripts by default (which is also mentioned under appropriate section in bash manual) and you should be able to enable that via `set -H`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I did that and showed it my question, it doesn't work.

Comment: @History_expansion let's make a new question out of it. Describe exactly what you want to happen. I'm curious why you need the behavior, and if sourcing the script could be an option. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffSchaller https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502526/using-interactives-shell-history-expansion-inside-a-script Thanks. I need this behavior because there's a blackbox in the company that reads a script (the script that I'm trying to write). I don't really need history expansion, I can do it in other ways,  I'm very curious in how to get history expansion to work to this effect.