# Using interactive's shell history expansion inside a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, history, history-expansion

I have the following Bash script

```
set -o histexpand
set -o history
pwd
lc="!!"
```

which, when I run it in an interactive shell, prints

```
/home/user
lc="pwd"
```

I'd like to, instead of getting `lc=pwd`, get the last command used in the interactive shell by using history expansion. So if I run `echo foo; ./script`, I hope to get

```
/home/user
lc="echo foo"
```

I tried to `set -H` in the script and it doesn't work.

Comment: Wouldn't the last command run in the interactive shell just be the script?  `$0` should work.  `$0 "$@"` if options are being used

Comment: @Jesse_b I think this depends on the shell, but that's just a detail because I could set `lc="!-2"`.

Comment: And what would you expect that to be? The last command ran in the interactive shell session from which the script was launched? What if the script isn't launched from an interactive shell? This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101), could you explain what your final objective is here?

Comment: Hi, terdon. My primary goal rests on black box details I'm unable to give, and I already found a workaround. Presently what I really want is to satisfy this curiosity (the one that I'm asking about). It's not a XY problem anymore. I'm setting as a condition (I do so in the question) that the script is ran from an interactive shell.

Comment: So, if you run `echo foo; ./script` in the interactive shell, you want `lc="echo foo"`?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I don't get why people would upvote terdon's comment after my reply and not say anything in reply to my comment.

Comment: probably because your question was unclear and lacked a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I had to pull clarification out of you.

Comment: @glennjackman I would understand that if I hadn't replied to the comment. But given that I did, it seems to me much more helpful to clarify why my comment doesn't properly address terdon's concerns, instead of me having to pull clarification out of people.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you won't be able to do what you want without parsing the history file: if the interactive shell has not written its history to the file, then a child shell (your script) will not have access to the recent history of the parent shell. It's a different story if your `source` your script, but then you have to account for the commands in the script.

Comment: @glennjackman I can do it using `history` and `awk`, just not using history expansion, if this matters.

Comment: You might want to research the `fc` command. For example `fc -l -1` shows the previous history entry.

Comment: @glennjackman Actually I can't do it using `history` and `awk`, I must have confused myself. Thanks.

Comment: @glennjackman Scratch that, I actually can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the shell's history expansion for getting the commands executed in the shell session previous to running your script  would not be doable unless the invoking shell saves its history to `$HISTFILE` after each executed command, which `bash` does not do by default, and exported the `HISTFILE` variable, which it does not need to do.

By default, the `bash` shell maintains an in-memory history for the current interactive shell session.  This history is saved to `$HISTFILE` when the shell session exits.  When a new session that enables command line history starts, the saved history is read from that file (assuming that new shell uses the same `$HISTFILE` value).

Your script, unless it has the `HISTFILE` variable inherited from its invoking environment, will at most be able to access command line history of its own session, i.e. the commands in the script.  If `HISTFILE` is exported, but if the invoking shell never saved its history to `$HISTFILE` before running the script, it would be impossible to get at the in-memory history of that parent shell session, and you would at most be able to access the historical history of sessions long since dead.

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused because I can access the interactive's shell history. Running the following script from a file will echo the last command in the interactive shell `lc=$(history | tail -2 | head -1 | cut -d" " -f 4); echo $lc`. Doesn't this contradict what you said? Or maybe I should ask what's different between `history` and history expansion that makes my comment and your answer non-contradictory?

Comment: @History_expansion I don't think it contradicts what I was saying. I don't know under what circumstances you run that, but without explicitly running `history -a` in the shell before executing the script (having the script use the same `$HISTORYFILE` value and using `set -o history`), you would not get the invoking shell's up to date history.

Comment: Can you please see https://pastebin.com/pwLVhDxy ? Isn't this evidence that it works as I say it does?

Comment: @History_expansion I don't know where you get that `echo` from in the output. I'm assuming you wanted to get `echo $-`?  This is what happens when I run: https://pastebin.com/aL0rGfpd

Comment: You're right about me wanting the whole command, I messed up with the `cut`. If I run using `bash` instead of the active shell (which in my case is Bash), I get the same as you. Otherwise it works like we can see in the link I shared.