# How to retrieve the command executed by command substitution for log reports

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, command, command-substitution

For Simplicity, consider the following:

```
x=$(java --version)
echo "x: $x"
```

It works how expected showing:

```
x: openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8)
OpenJDK Client VM Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode)
```

What I need is the following:

```
x=$(java --version)
echo "x: $x"
echo "The '???' command was executed"
```

Therefore the output should be

```
x: openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8)
OpenJDK Client VM Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode)
The 'java -version' command was executed
```

With what can be replaced `???`?

I already do a research and I found about `set +x/-x` but does not apply here in a 100%

Comment: Really, does `echo $x` print output with newlines?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk seems you are correct - the difference is between use `-version` vs `--version` in some way - I did realize `echo $x` prints nothing (I just commented) - the output comes from the command itself

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, why - in a script - you wouldn't know which command had just been executed. But, for the fun of it:

```
exec 2>tmpfile; set -x
x=$(java --version)
set +x; exec 2>&1
awk  'sub(/^\+\+\+/, "") {print "The \"" $0 "\" command was executed."} ' tmpfile
The " java --version" command was executed.
```

The `awk` command removes the `$PS4` characters (which, in this case, are RE meta chars as well) introduced by the `-x` (xtrace) option, then prints the required line. The tmpfile should be removed afterwards.

Comment: @RudicC I am creating the scripts for automation purposes for some most complex commands working with parameters (based in user input) and including more pipes

Comment: Pls consider to add an explanation of the `awk` command used

Answer (score 1):

In interactive shell when history expansion is enabled you can do:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
$ command="!!"
$ echo "$command"
java -version
```

Comment: I am creating the scripts for automation purposes for some most complex commands working with parameters (based in user input) and including more pipes - so all works through Menu options.

Comment: Consider to indicate how enable/disable _history expansion_ - seems it is disabled in my side

Answer (score 1):

As @Arkadiusz Drabczyk says `!!` is the last command executed.

This trick have other interesting use ways, as `man bash` says :

> !-n
> Refer to the current command line minus n.

so : `!-2` is what you want.

The down side is that this work only in interactive shell.

To enable that behavior in a script you need to specify it to `bash` with the following option :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -H
set -o history
x=$(gcc -v 2>&1) # Sorry i dont like Java
echo "x is $x"
echo "Last cmd is " !-2 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

---

Or you can just enable `history` inside you script and parse its output:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o history
x=$(gcc -v 2>&1)
echo "x is $x"
last_cmd=$(history | sed -n '1s/^ * *//p')
echo "The cmd executed is $last_cmd"
```

The part `... | sed ...` cuts off the format used by the `history` command.
In my system, `history`, print out :

```
  2142  ./test2.sh 
  2143  cat test2.sh 
  2144  history
```

On other systems, the date and time may also be printed.

---

See these for interesting info on how [enable history inside a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script) and [history expansion inside a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384861/is-history-expansion-disabled-in-scripts)