# How can I check if a shell is login/interactive/batch in fish?

Tags: shell, login, fish

I want to be able to check if a `fish` shell is being run in login, interactive, or batch mode, and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26676/8474) only discusses `bash`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [`status` command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#status):

```
$ fish -c 'status --is-interactive; and echo yes; or echo no'
no
$ status --is-interactive; and echo yes; or echo no
yes
```

Also, `status --is-login`. That should cover your bases.

Comment: As of fish version 3.3.1, its `status is-login`.